# How to solve SDE: $ dX_t = \bigg(\sqrt{1+X_t^2}+\frac{1}{2}X_t \bigg)dt + \sqrt{1+X_t^2} dW_t$

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-differential-equations

#### Problem:

---

I would like to find a solution to the following SDE:
$$ dX_t = \bigg(\sqrt{1+X_t^2}+\frac{1}{2}X_t \bigg)dt + \sqrt{1+X_t^2} dW_t$$

##### Calculations:

by Ito's lemma: $$df(t,X_t) = \Bigg(f_t(t,X_t)+ \bigg(\sqrt{1+X_t^2}+\frac{1}{2}X_t \bigg)f_x(t,X_t)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+\frac{5}{4}X_t^2+X_t\sqrt{1+X_t^2}\bigg)f_{xx}(t, X_t)  \Bigg)dt + f_x(t,X_t)\sqrt{1+X_t^2} dW_t$$

##### My research:

---

In the Vasicek model: $$dR_t = (\alpha - \beta R_t)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

We choose $f$ such that:

1. $f_t(t,x)$ doesn't depend on $x$. So $f(t,x) = g(t)x + h(t)$
2. $f_t(t,R_t) - \beta R_t f_x(t,R_t) = 0 $   **Why ?**

From there after few calculations, we find that $f(t,x) = xe^{\beta t}$

(I don't fully undurstand step (2). )

In the CIR model, which looks similar (at least it has a square root): $$dr_t = a(b-r_t)dt +\sigma\sqrt{(r_t)} dW_t$$
the $Z_t = e^{at}r_t$.

How to find $f$ for the orginal SDE? In order to solve the SDE by finding $Z_t$ like in CIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We observe there is the term $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, that makes me think to use [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions) and [their inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions) (for example : $1+\text{sinh}^2(x) = \text{cosh}^2(x)$).

Let's denote $Y_t = \text{arsinh}(X_t)$. By Ito's lemma, we have
$$\begin{align}
dY_t &=d (\text{arsinh}(X_t))\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}}dX_t-\frac{1}{2}\frac{X_t}{(1+X_t^2)^{3/2}}<dX_t,dX_t> \\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{X_t}{(1+X_t^2)^{1/2}} \right)dt+dW_t- \frac{1}{2}\frac{X_t}{(1+X_t^2)^{1/2}}dt\\
&= dt+dW_t
\end{align}$$
Then, with a constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$
$$Y_t = t+W_t+c$$
or
$$X_t =\text{sinh}(Y_t) =\color{red}{\text{sinh}(t+W_t+c) = \frac{e^{t+W_t+c} - e^{-(t+W_t+c)}}{2}} $$

**PS**: don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question. Don't forget either to accept the answers of your previous questions. ;-).

Comment: In the second line of the equation with $dY_t$ the <> sign, the only bell that rings what <> might be is total variation distance. Could you please explain this bit?

Comment: or you use it to denote $dX_tdX_t$ ?

Comment: @MichaelW Yes, I want to denote $dX_tdX_t$ (I think the total variation distance should be denoted by $<dX_t,dX_t>$ ?)

Comment: Thank you for clarification :)

Comment: The quadratic variation is usually denoted as $d\langle X\rangle_t$ or for two processes $d[U,V]_t$.